# No newline before EOF?

Tags: c

I was solving one of the exercises from K&R but I'm having a minor problem. 
The exercise is to print a histogram of the length of words in its input.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main(){
    //Histogram of the length of words
    int c, state, len, i;
    state = OUT;

    printf("Histogram\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '\r'){
            state = IN;
            len++;
        } else if (state == IN){
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                putchar('[');
                putchar(']');
            }
            len = 0;
            putchar('\n');
            state = OUT;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The text file I used was:

```
Hello World! This is a text
```

The output of the program was:

```
Histogram
[][][][][]
[][][][][][]
[][][][]
[][]
[]
```

As it can be seen, the program terminated before printing out the histogram for the last word 'text'. 
Is this because the text editor on Windows does not automatically put '\r\n' at the end? If so, how can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout);` at the end of your program.

Comment: Well, you could open the file in a text editor and add a newline on the last line.  Alternatives are to do one more step of printing when you exit the loop if len is not 0.

Comment: Your loop terminates when you don't want it to terminate. Change the termination condition to be what you really want. (EOF *and* len==0).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop end when `getchar()` return `EOF` so you never go in the `else if` at the end.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Histogram\n");

  size_t len = 0;
  bool running = true;
  while (running) {
    switch (getchar()) {
    case EOF:
      running = false;
    case ' ':
    case '\n':
    case '\t':
    case '\r':
      if (len != 0) {
        printf("\n");
        len = 0;
      }
      break;
    default:
      printf("[]");
      len++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the tests around:

```
while (true)
{
    const int c = getchar();
    if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '\r' && c != EOF)
    {
        state = IN;
        len++;
    }
    else if (state == IN)
    {
        // ...
    }

    if (c == EOF) break;
}
```